# Pronunciation of T before W

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce it would, it was, etc ( in American English) ? That is, how do you pronounce the "T" when it precedes a semi-vowel like w? Is it a stop T, or even no T at all when pronounced fast ? When followed by a vowel, it's a "flap T" ( ex: " it is") , and when followed by a consonant, it's a full T ( ex: "it looks"), as far as I can see, but this I can't nail down.

Comment: Consult an online dictionary that has "buttons" to pronounce words.  Check out "two" "twenty", "twins", "twitter, "twirl", "twist", "twitch", etc.

Comment: It's not the same thing.  T has here an incipient position, and it's a no brainer, they're all full T's. "It was" on the other hand, I'm positive people pronounce differently. I want to know if it's only me, or it is in fact a peculiarity of American English/ fast speech

Comment: Rapid pronunciation modifies many word sounds.  "It was" tends to turn into "twas".  Or, in some cases, the T sound turns halfway to a D sound.

Comment: In American English, at normal speech rate, I would say [ɪʔ'wʊd] for _it would_, substituting a glottal stop for the [t], or if you prefer, using the [ʔ] "gloʔal stop" allophone of /t/. The actual shape of the /d/ at the end depends on what follows ***it***.

Comment: @hotlicks maybe 'twas' in BrE, but not at all in AmE. Word final t us unreleased and converts to a light glottal stop it dropped altogether in 'it was'

Comment: John Lawler, just as I thought. So it wasn't just me. Thanks a lot for the answer. Thanks everybody.